# Structuring redux, redux-saga and normalizr

Tags: redux, redux-saga, normalizr

So I would like to use these three technologies. My idea is to have a reducer which handles all my entities, aided by normalizr.

redux-saga would listen for `ENTITIES_REQUESTED` action, run a saga which requests the entities, and makes a `ENTITIES_RECEIVED` action, which would be handled by a reducer which calls normalizr and stores the entities in the `entities` slice.

For deleting an entity, two things have to happen: the entity must be removed from the state, and a side effect must happen which will remove the entity from the server (side point: I know some will claim that removing from state is *also* a side effect, but I don't think redux-saga works on that notion).

So I can have a `ENTITY_REMOVED` action, which will remove the entity from the state, and a saga listening for that, which will handle the api call.

Now let's say I have a table, with a bulk delete feature for a table. The table is "powered" by a reducer that accepts an action `DATA_OPTIONS_SET`. The reducer updates things like current page, filters, etc. There would also be a saga from listens to this and calls the API to return the new data set.

I would like to have a bulk delete feature which at a high level, deletes all the entities, and when that is done, refresh the table.

If I loop over the entities to delete, and dispatch an `ENTITY_REMOVED` action, I will how no way of knowing when those deletes are done, so that I could refresh the table.

If I manually call the saga that deletes the entities, `ENTITY_REMOVED` will never have been dispatched, so the entity is not removed from the store.

Does this mean my architecture is incorrect and I took a wrong turn somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach your problem as follows: create delete saga which would

1. Wait for ENTITIY_REMOVE_REQUEST action with entity id as parameter
2. Call an appropriate endpoint to delete entity from server
3. If api call was success dispatch ENTITY_REMOVED action which will remove entity from state.

Of course this is not the only option and much details will depend on how your api is build. Instead of removing each entity manually in point 3. you could dispatch an action that will fetch all entities from the server and updated your whole state with new entities list, or you could bulk up and pass all entities that need to be deleted in single api call in point 2.

Comment: The thing that I don't like about ENTITY_REMOVE_REQUEST is that it's action with no meaning in terms of the state of the app. It's only purpose is to start a side effect, which seems awkward to me.

Comment: in terms in state of the app it represents sequence of actions (or computations) which may fail. Since you want to update your state only if the network request to the server succeed. If you do not check for network operation success your app state can be different from the state at the server.  I think that such organization leads to quite clear sagas, however if you find some better solution I'll be happy to learn

Comment: I think the saga can handle the failing situation by simply emitting a compensating action if something went wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly: you go ahead and update redux state by deleting an item, which will make some of your components rerender. Next you make an api call and in case it fail you fire additional action to add item you just deleted from state? It seems rather complicated as you will have to store temporary item which you are deleting and it will make your components blink which I think is gonna be confusing for the user.

Take a look at redux-saga real-world example. They seem to be making request actions for any api call and emiting success/failure action as a followup.

Comment: The flow looks like this:
1) Remove entity from redux state
2) Trigger side effect which makes API call
3) If something goes wrong, we would notify the user, and place the entity right back in the state.

The UI is completely optimistic, and the server is completely transparent.

Comment: I so see that the real world example is making an "empty" action like that, so I see it's an accepted practice, as much as I find it awkward (harks back to the "event emitter" days, a little). So I will award you the points.